# How to close WebView on url change

Tags: android, facebook, webview

I know I asked this a lot of times but I still can't close the webview and it still redirects to facebook home.

```
public class FBShareAll extends Activity {

private WebView webView;
String testAddress = "some string";
String myUrl;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fbshare_all);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);


    Intent get = getIntent();
    final String QC = get.getExtras().getString("QC");
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    if(QC.equals("Google")){


         String title = "Quezon City Guide";
            String desc = "Your Number One City Guide!";
            String image = "http://s21.postimg.org/6sq49njub/launchertrans.png";

            testAddress ="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?m2w&s=100&p[title]="+title+"&p[summary]="+desc+"&p[url]=http://www.sample.com&p[images][0]="+image;

        if(myUrl == null){
            myUrl = testAddress;
        }
        webView.loadUrl(myUrl);

    }




}

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        myUrl = url;



        if(myUrl.equals("http://m.facebook.com/?_rdr")){
            ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)webView.getParent();
            if(vg != null)
               vg.removeView(webView);
            webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            finish();
        }



   //   else 
            view.loadUrl(url);

        Log.i("URL", myUrl);

        if(myUrl.equals("http://m.facebook.com/?_rdr")){
            ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)webView.getParent();
            if(vg != null)
               vg.removeView(webView);
            webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            finish();
        }

        return true;
 }


}

public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    finish();
 }


public void onRestart(){
    super.onRestart();
    finish();
    }

    }
```

It only closes the webview if I do this.

```
if(myUrl.equals(url)){
  finish();
 }
```

I don't know why it only closes if it detected the original url. Can someone please help? Thanks!

Comment: Can you, log and check the url that is passed as a parameter to public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) method.

Comment: I did. `http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?m2w&s=100&p[title]=Quezon City Guide&p[summary]=Your Number One City Guide!&p[url]=http://www.sample.com&p[images][0]=http://s21.postimg.org/6sq49njub/launchertrans.png`.

Comment: After Sharing it show the url in the log `http://m.facebook.com/?_rdr`

Comment: hey i think u need to clear the cache try this code webview.clearCache(true);

Comment: CAN SOMEONE PLEASE HELP? :(